# Overwriting Wordpress default stylesheet

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Good Day.

I am using a Wordpress theme and I want to add my own custom CSS. Now I have tried adding my own separate stylesheet after all the other php stylesheet calls in the header.php file. I tried editing the stylesheet in Appearance>Editor, and I even added !important to ALL my styles. But Wordpress keeps overwriting my styles with the default stylesheet.

Now I read a bit about registering/enqueuing stylesheets in the functions.wp-styles.php but the code there is french to me...I do not know where to add my css...

Here is the code in the functions.wp-styles.php page: Should I define it here?
Your help will be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
/**
 * BackPress styles procedural API.
 *
 * @package BackPress
 * @since r79
 */

/**
 * Display styles that are in the queue or part of $handles.
 *
 * @since r79
 * @uses do_action() Calls 'wp_print_styles' hook.
 * @global object $wp_styles The WP_Styles object for printing styles.
 *
 * @param array|bool $handles Styles to be printed. An empty array prints the queue,
 *  an array with one string prints that style, and an array of strings prints those styles.
 * @return bool True on success, false on failure.
 */
function wp_print_styles( $handles = false ) {
    if ( '' === $handles ) // for wp_head
        $handles = false;

    if ( ! $handles )
        do_action( 'wp_print_styles' );

    global $wp_styles;
    if ( ! is_a( $wp_styles, 'WP_Styles' ) ) {
        if ( ! did_action( 'init' ) )
            _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, sprintf( __( 'Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the %1$s, %2$s, or %3$s hooks.' ),
                '<code>wp_enqueue_scripts</code>', '<code>admin_enqueue_scripts</code>', '<code>init</code>' ), '3.3' );

        if ( !$handles )
            return array(); // No need to instantiate if nothing is there.
        else
            $wp_styles = new WP_Styles();
    }

    return $wp_styles->do_items( $handles );
}

/**
 * Adds extra CSS.
 *
 * Works only if the stylesheet has already been added.
 * Accepts a string $data containing the CSS. If two or more CSS code blocks are
 * added to the same stylesheet $handle, they will be printed in the order
 * they were added, i.e. the latter added styles can redeclare the previous.
 *
 * @since 3.3.0
 * @see WP_Scripts::add_inline_style()
 */
function wp_add_inline_style( $handle, $data ) {
    global $wp_styles;
    if ( ! is_a( $wp_styles, 'WP_Styles' ) ) {
        if ( ! did_action( 'init' ) )
            _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, sprintf( __( 'Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the %1$s, %2$s, or %3$s hooks.' ),
                '<code>wp_enqueue_scripts</code>', '<code>admin_enqueue_scripts</code>', '<code>init</code>' ), '3.3' );
        $wp_styles = new WP_Styles();
    }

    return $wp_styles->add_inline_style( $handle, $data );
}

/**
 * Register CSS style file.
 *
 * @since r79
 * @see WP_Styles::add() For additional information.
 * @global object $wp_styles The WP_Styles object for printing styles.
 * @link http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types List of CSS media types.
 *
 * @param string $handle Name of the stylesheet.
 * @param string|bool $src Path to the stylesheet from the root directory of WordPress. Example: '/css/mystyle.css'.
 * @param array $deps Array of handles of any stylesheet that this stylesheet depends on.
 *  (Stylesheets that must be loaded before this stylesheet.) Pass an empty array if there are no dependencies.
 * @param string|bool $ver String specifying the stylesheet version number. Set to null to disable.
 *  Used to ensure that the correct version is sent to the client regardless of caching.
 * @param string $media The media for which this stylesheet has been defined.
 */
function wp_register_style( $handle, $src, $deps = array(), $ver = false, $media = 'all' ) {
    global $wp_styles;
    if ( ! is_a( $wp_styles, 'WP_Styles' ) ) {
        if ( ! did_action( 'init' ) )
            _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, sprintf( __( 'Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the %1$s, %2$s, or %3$s hooks.' ),
                '<code>wp_enqueue_scripts</code>', '<code>admin_enqueue_scripts</code>', '<code>init</code>' ), '3.3' );
        $wp_styles = new WP_Styles();
    }

    $wp_styles->add( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
}

/**
 * Remove a registered CSS file.
 *
 * @since r79
 * @see WP_Styles::remove() For additional information.
 * @global object $wp_styles The WP_Styles object for printing styles.
 *
 * @param string $handle Name of the stylesheet.
 */
function wp_deregister_style( $handle ) {
    global $wp_styles;
    if ( ! is_a( $wp_styles, 'WP_Styles' ) ) {
        if ( ! did_action( 'init' ) )
            _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, sprintf( __( 'Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the %1$s, %2$s, or %3$s hooks.' ),
                '<code>wp_enqueue_scripts</code>', '<code>admin_enqueue_scripts</code>', '<code>init</code>' ), '3.3' );
        $wp_styles = new WP_Styles();
    }

    $wp_styles->remove( $handle );
}

/**
 * Enqueue a CSS style file.
 *
 * Registers the style if src provided (does NOT overwrite) and enqueues.
 *
 * @since r79
 * @see WP_Styles::add(), WP_Styles::enqueue()
 * @global object $wp_styles The WP_Styles object for printing styles.
 * @link http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types List of CSS media types.
 *
 * @param string $handle Name of the stylesheet.
 * @param string|bool $src Path to the stylesheet from the root directory of WordPress. Example: '/css/mystyle.css'.
 * @param array $deps Array of handles (names) of any stylesheet that this stylesheet depends on.
 *  (Stylesheets that must be loaded before this stylesheet.) Pass an empty array if there are no dependencies.
 * @param string|bool $ver String specifying the stylesheet version number, if it has one. This parameter
 *  is used to ensure that the correct version is sent to the client regardless of caching, and so should be included
 *  if a version number is available and makes sense for the stylesheet.
 * @param string $media The media for which this stylesheet has been defined.
 */
function wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src = false, $deps = array(), $ver = false, $media = 'all' ) {
    global $wp_styles;
    if ( ! is_a( $wp_styles, 'WP_Styles' ) ) {
        if ( ! did_action( 'init' ) )
            _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, sprintf( __( 'Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the %1$s, %2$s, or %3$s hooks.' ),
                '<code>wp_enqueue_scripts</code>', '<code>admin_enqueue_scripts</code>', '<code>init</code>' ), '3.3' );
        $wp_styles = new WP_Styles();
    }

    if ( $src ) {
        $_handle = explode('?', $handle);
        $wp_styles->add( $_handle[0], $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
    }
    $wp_styles->enqueue( $handle );
}

/**
 * Remove an enqueued style.
 *
 * @since WP 3.1
 * @see WP_Styles::dequeue() For parameter information.
 */
function wp_dequeue_style( $handle ) {
    global $wp_styles;
    if ( ! is_a( $wp_styles, 'WP_Styles' ) ) {
        if ( ! did_action( 'init' ) )
            _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, sprintf( __( 'Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the %1$s, %2$s, or %3$s hooks.' ),
                '<code>wp_enqueue_scripts</code>', '<code>admin_enqueue_scripts</code>', '<code>init</code>' ), '3.3' );
        $wp_styles = new WP_Styles();
    }

    $wp_styles->dequeue( $handle );
}

/**
 * Check whether style has been added to WordPress Styles.
 *
 * By default, checks if the style has been enqueued. You can also
 * pass 'registered' to $list, to see if the style is registered,
 * and you can check processing statuses with 'to_do' and 'done'.
 *
 * @since WP unknown; BP unknown
 * @global object $wp_styles The WP_Styles object for printing styles.
 *
 * @param string $handle Name of the stylesheet.
 * @param string $list Optional. Defaults to 'enqueued'. Values are
 *  'registered', 'enqueued' (or 'queue'), 'to_do', and 'done'.
 * @return bool Whether style is in the list.
 */
function wp_style_is( $handle, $list = 'enqueued' ) {
    global $wp_styles;
    if ( ! is_a( $wp_styles, 'WP_Styles' ) ) {
        if ( ! did_action( 'init' ) )
            _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, sprintf( __( 'Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the %1$s, %2$s, or %3$s hooks.' ),
                '<code>wp_enqueue_scripts</code>', '<code>admin_enqueue_scripts</code>', '<code>init</code>' ), '3.3' );
        $wp_styles = new WP_Styles();
    }

    return (bool) $wp_styles->query( $handle, $list );
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're targeting the correct classes when you edit stylesheet.css? Have you done a force browser refresh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a function inside the functions.php page - Which is located in the themes root directory...

```
function wpse87681_enqueue_custom_stylesheets() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'mytheme-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom.css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse87681_enqueue_custom_stylesheets', 10 );
```

Just add custom.css (which is your custom code) into the root folder as well(same folder as functions.php). I believe that will do the trick

The 10 referenced in the last line of the code is the default priority. If it does not work the first time, try making the priority 11

Comment: Its a pleasure. Now go help someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the JetPack plugin an option for you?  They offer a custom css module function which you can choose to either add on to the existing CSS or replace the theme's CSS.  I would recommend you look at this first if you haven't already.

[JetPack Custom CSS](http://jetpack.me/support/custom-css/)

Comment: Thank you Joseph. I do not however want to replace the default css entirely, I only want to make changes, but the damn hard coded css makes it impossible (in the rookie sense...)Will this plugin ovveride styles by registering and enqueuing stylesheets in the source code...?

Comment: When you say hard coded CSS, do you mean style definitions as attributes within the elements themselves?

Comment: no, I mean the styles are called by custom php functions. So simply linking to a stylesheet in your head will just be overridden by the custom functions implementing the css.

Answer (score 0):

DextrousDave's response is good.

I would recommend, however, that you make a child theme, instead of adding files to the theme folder. The reason is that if you update the theme after making changes, it will wipe out your changes. To make a child theme, create a new folder in the "Themes" folder, and call it whatever you like (BackpressChildTheme, or DavidVanStaden, or whatever).

Then add a stylesheet ("style.css"), and include the following code at the top:

```
/*
Theme Name:     Backpress Child Theme, or whatever you want to call it
Theme URI:      http://notreallynecessary.com
Description:    Child theme for the BackPress theme 
Author:         David Van Staden
Author URI:     http://davidvanstaden.com/about/
Template:       BackPress
Version:        0.1.0
*/
```

Note that the most important line is "Template: ", make sure that matches the *folder* name of the 'parent' theme (BackPress).

Next add a blank php file, functions.php, and add the function that DextrousDave suggested, except where it says get_template_directory_uri, change it to get_stylesheet_directory_uri.

Now, if you update your theme, all your changes that are made in your child theme will be preserved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it does not work. How is wordpress suppose to know it should load the files in Antoher theme folder? It is not as if the theme (BackpressChildTheme) is activated...?

Comment: That's how child themes work, it's something that wordpress recognizes and deals with. You can read more here:http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

What happened when you tried?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if I made it clear, but you need to activate the child theme, as you would any theme.